# Can I automatically update Hibernate pojos and mappings in Netbeans after adding a new table?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, netbeans

I already have hibernate mapping files and pojos created by Netbeans to which I've added named queries and extra methods.

Now I've added another table to the database and a foreign key column to an existing table.

It's not a big problem with just one table to add the mappings by hand but it gets tedious and error prone with more.

What I do at the moment is use a wizard to create a whole new set of classes and mappings in a new package and manually merge them, which in itself is prone to mistakes.

Is there a way to automagically update the .hbm and java files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are trying to acheive is not the best way of keeping the database and hibernate in sync. If possible, you should do the other way around - make changes in the hibernate mappings, and let them be reflected in the database.

After all, it's your object model that matters, not the database representation.

Check the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html). If set to `update`, it will update the underlying database with the appropriate columns and constraints based on the changes in your hibernate mappings.

Answer (score 2):

NetBeans has [Reverse Engineering support](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteWorthyMilestone1NB65#Hibernate_.28Available_via_Development_Update_center_for_M1.29) since 6.5 but it doesn't seem to offers **round-trip**. So, sadly, I think that you'll have to stick with your current approach.